# ORACLE SQL - Compare dates without join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a very large table of data 1+ billion rows. If I try to join that table to itself to do a comparison, the cost on the estimated plan is unrunnable (cost: 226831405289150). Is there a way I can achieve the same results as the query below without a join, perhaps an over partition?

What I need to do is make sure another event did not happen within 24 hours before or after the one with the wildcare was received.

Thanks so much for your help!

```
select e2.SYSTEM_NO,
       min(e2.DT) as dt
from   SYSTEM_EVENT e2
       inner join table1.event el2
       on el2.event_id = e2.event_id 
       left join ( Select se.DT
                   from  SYSTEM_EVENT se
                   where
                         --fails
                         (   se.event_id in ('101','102','103','104')
                         --restores
                          or se.event_id in ('106','107','108','109')
                         )
                  ) e3
       on e3.dt-e2.dt between .0001 and 1
       or e3.dt-e2.dt between -1 and .0001
where  el2.descr like '%WILDCARE%'
and    e3.dt is null
and    e2.REC_STS_CD = 'A'
group by e2.SYSTEM_NO
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having any test data it is difficult to determine what you are trying to achieve but it appears you could try using an analytic function with a range window:

```
SELECT system_no,
       MIN( dt ) AS dt
FROM   (
  SELECT system_no,
         dt,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN (  se.event_id in ('101','102','103','104')   --fails
                OR se.event_id in ('106','107','108','109') ) --restores
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER (
           ORDER BY dt
           RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
         ) AS num
  FROM   system_event
) se
WHERE  num = 0
AND    REC_STS_CD = 'A'
AND    EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table1.event te
  WHERE  te.descr like '%WILDCARE%'
  AND    te.event_id = se.event_id
)
GROUP BY system_no
```

Comment: @mtd thank you, this is very close I think! but I can't grab se.event_id to perform the exists check because it's not in the select statement of se

Comment: EDIT--- I included it.. COST is way down to the last successful run levels, trying it now!

Comment: I had to change a couple things (since you guys didn't have example data) but was able to use this for my final solution. The OVER had to be partitioned by system_no. I also added a filter with all the event_ids of the '%WILDCARE%' in a where statement of system_event which brought the cost way down (runs under 15 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

This is not direct answer for your question but it is a bit too long for comment.

How old data may be inserted? 48h window means you need to check only subset of data not whole 1bilion row table if data is inserted incrementally. So if it is please reduce data in comparison by some `with` clause or `temporary table`.

If you still need to compare along whole table I would go for partitioning by `event_id` or other attribute if there is better partition. And compare each group separately.

`where  el2.descr like '%WILDCARE%'` is performance killer for such huge table.

Comment: Still you can partition by `event_id` and try use better condition than `LIKE %WILD%`